# Cassandra interprets queries incorrectly

Tags: cassandra

I have a table `X` with a binary column `a` as my key.
This is a pretty large table with >10M records. When I run this query, I see the following response:

`Received warning (1 of 1) "Read 5000 live rows and 2004 tombstone cells for query SELECT * FROM db.X WHERE a = 086eb4bd16043dbb6bab843cf5c06895 LIMIT 5000 (see tombstone_warn_threshold)" for query "SELECT b AS col_b, c, d AS col_d, e AS col_e, f, g FROM X WHERE a > 0x086EB4BD16043DBB6BAB843CF5C06895"`

I'm having pretty serious performance issues and my current guess that its because of this misinterpretation by Cassandra (hopefully because of my bad configuration)

Comment: What do you think is wrong here? The fact that there is a limit being appended?

Comment: The performance problems are almost certainly due to bad data model causing you to scan over many tombstones. Posting your data model will be very helpful in helping us explain what's going on.

Comment: @RussS, My real problem is that I am observing a degradation in read performance. The log output is merely a symptom. The thing is I have never queried for `a _>_ 08....` This looks like some sort of misinterpretation by Cassandra. All my modules ever query for binary equivalence like `a = 0x...`

Comment: @JeffJirsa, Let me try to get this. Thanks for your response though

Answer (score 0):

You are presented a warning because you have too many tombstones around.

> tombstone_warn_threshold 
>       (Default: 1000) The maximum number of tombstones a query can scan before warning.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

If more tombstones accumulate and wont get compacted soon there is also a failure_threshold.

That happens if you delete a lot of data - one delete in fact is a write of one tombstone. Your query with a limit of 5000 can potentially read many tombstones from deleted rows and that is a serious performance issue.

Could you post your table definition? And your use case?

I saw this pattern when trying to use cassanda as a queue or with ttl'ed data with short ttls. The first might be an antipattern for cassandra, the latter is worth a look at TimeWindowCompactionStrategy.

Comment: I have to check if I am setting TTLs. Will get back on your response. Thanks